# Unable to locate canvas elements present on the page using casperjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, casperjs

I am new to casperjs and still exploring it. One problem i am facing here is i am unable to locate element on the page. basically there is one plot and i want to use `this.test.assertExixts` but it is failing.

the element i want to locate on the page's html code is:

```
<div id="htmlwidget_container" style="position: absolute; top: 40px; right: 40px; bottom: 40px; left: 40px;">
<div id="htmlwidget-db33fd07312733aaf5e4" class="dygraphs html-widget html-widget-static-bound" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div style="text-align: left; position: relative; width: 520px; height: 320px;">
        <canvas style="position: absolute; width: 520px; height: 320px;" width="520" height="320"/>
        <canvas style="position: absolute; width: 520px; height: 320px;" width="520" height="320"/>
        <canvas class="dygraph-rangesel-bgcanvas" style="position: absolute; z-index: 9; top: 280px; left: 56px; width: 459px; height: 40px;" width="459" height="40"/>
        <canvas class="dygraph-rangesel-fgcanvas" style="position: absolute; z-index: 9; cursor: default; top: 280px; left: 56px; width: 459px; height: 40px;" width="459" height="40"/>
        <img class="dygraph-rangesel-zoomhandle" style="position: absolute; z-index: 10; visibility: visible; cursor: col-resize; left: 113.737px; top: 292px;" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAQCAYAAADESFVDAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAAZiS0dEANAAzwDP4Z7KegAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAAd0SU1FB9sHGw0cMqdt1UwAAAAZdEVYdENvbW1lbnQAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIEdJTVBXgQ4XAAAAaElEQVQoz+3SsRFAQBCF4Z9WJM8KCDVwownl6YXsTmCUsyKGkZzcl7zkz3YLkypgAnreFmDEpHkIwVOMfpdi9CEEN2nGpFdwD03yEqDtOgCaun7sqSTDH32I1pQA2Pb9sZecAxc5r3IAb21d6878xsAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="9" height="16"/>
        <img class="dygraph-rangesel-zoomhandle" style="position: absolute; z-index: 10; visibility: visible; cursor: col-resize; left: 424.919px; top: 292px;" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAQCAYAAADESFVDAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAAZiS0dEANAAzwDP4Z7KegAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAAd0SU1FB9sHGw0cMqdt1UwAAAAZdEVYdENvbW1lbnQAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIEdJTVBXgQ4XAAAAaElEQVQoz+3SsRFAQBCF4Z9WJM8KCDVwownl6YXsTmCUsyKGkZzcl7zkz3YLkypgAnreFmDEpHkIwVOMfpdi9CEEN2nGpFdwD03yEqDtOgCaun7sqSTDH32I1pQA2Pb9sZecAxc5r3IAb21d6878xsAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="9" height="16"/>
        <input style="display: none; position: absolute; z-index: 10; top: 231px; left: 57px;" size="2" type="text"/>
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 515px; height: 28px; text-align: center; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; z-index: 10;">
            <div class="dygraph-legend" style="position: absolute; font-size: 14px; z-index: 10; width: 250px; top: 28px; left: 264px; background: white none repeat scroll 0% 0%; line-height: normal; text-align: left; overflow: hidden;">
```

and casperjs code part is :

```
casper.then(function () {
    this.waitForSelector("#htmlwidget-0fa8344710bef2a7dcfa > div:nth-child(1) > canvas:nth-child(2)", function () {
        this.test.assertExists("#htmlwidget-0fa8344710bef2a7dcfa > div:nth-child(1) > canvas:nth-child(2)", "Confirmed!. element exists");
    });
});
```

also tried to get element info using below but it is returning anything

```
casper.then(function () {
    var temp = this.getElementInfo("#htmlwidget_container").tag;
    this.echo('Image :' + temp);
});
```

Comment: well, there's no element with id `htmlwidget-0fa8344710bef2a7dcfa` so, of course you can't find it

Comment: perhaps you want `div[id^=htmlwidget-] > div:nth-child(1) ... etc ...`

Comment: @JaromandaX, i even tried using `this.test.assertExists("#htmlwidget_container");` but still it fails